# Error formating dates in nvd3

Tags: javascript, d3.js, nvd3.js

I am showing a simple chart using nvd3, and I am getting a NaN when formatting from a string date. When I use code with explicit javascript dates (like the comment out var testdata). graph is showed correct. Here is my code. But I would like to use strings, what is wrong here?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <link href="novus-nvd3-153163a/build/nv.d3.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.5.2/d3.min.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
    <script src="novus-nvd3-153163a/build/nv.d3.js"></script>
     <script src="novus-nvd3-153163a/examples/lib/stream_layers.js"></script>
    <style>
        text {
            font: 12px sans-serif;
        }
        svg {
            display: block;
        }
        html, body, {
            margin: 0px;
            padding: 0px;
            height: 100%;
            width: 100%;
        }
          #chart1 {
          width : 600px;
          height: 400px;
          }
    </style>
</head>
<body class='with-3d-shadow with-transitions'>
<div id="chart1" ><svg></svg></div>

<script>
    var dates = [new Date(2013,1,1).getTime(),  new Date(2014,1,1).getTime(), new Date(2015,1,1).getTime()];
    //var testdata = [{"key":"Sales","values":[{"x":dates[0],"y":2972948},{"x":dates[1],"y":2659151},{"x":dates[2],"y":11381859}]},{"key":"Rentability","values":[{"x":dates[0],"y":32.9},{"x":dates[1],"y":30.6},{"x":dates[2],"y":78.5}]}];
    var testdata = [{"key":"Sales","values":[{"x":"2013-1-1","y":2972948},{"x":"2014-1-1","y":2659151},{"x":"2015-1-1","y":11381859}]},{"key":"Rentability","values":[{"x":"2013-1-1","y":32.9},{"x":"2014-1-1","y":30.6},{"x":"2015-1-1","y":78.5}]}];
    testdata[0].type = "line";
    testdata[0].yAxis = 1;
    testdata[1].type = "line";
    testdata[1].yAxis = 2;

    nv.addGraph(function() {
        var chart = nv.models.multiChart()
            .margin({top: 30, right: 60, bottom: 50, left: 70})
            .color(d3.scale.category10().range());
        chart.xAxis.tickFormat(function(d) { 
            console.log(d);
            return d3.time.format('%Y')(new Date(d)); 
            });
        chart.xAxis.tickValues(dates);
        chart.yAxis1.tickFormat(d3.format(',.1f'));
        chart.yAxis2.tickFormat(d3.format(',.1f'));
        d3.select('#chart1 svg')
            .datum(testdata)
            .transition().duration(0).call(chart);
        return chart;
    });
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Please review your description. The commented out line seems as if it would **not** work, while the line with Javascript dates is not commented out.

Comment: Yes thanks I comment out the other line.

Answer (score 0):

Well, unfortunately, AFAIK nv3d does not support Strings as dates. I ran into the same problem some months ago.

I mainly see two possible solutions here:

1. If JavaScript is your main data source, use `Date.parse()` to convert your Strings into JavaScript dates.
2. Otherwise, if generating this JavaScript on a server, change your server code to render JavaScript dates.

To avoid timezone issues, you should carefully read the `Date.parse()` documentation, e.g. here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/parse

To make it short - if you pass Strings in ISO format into `Date.parse()`, you will get UTC values (unless a timezone is specified). So `Date.parse("2012-03-02")` could result in `2012-03-01 23:00:00` or similar effects when it is being rendered (using your local timezone settings, if you are not in GMT timezone).

Comment: Funny enough, I already use nv3d with string as dates on other examples.

Comment: OK, why don't you post that as working example here, too? Would help to find what may be wrong... As far as I remember, it may work with some types of charts, but with others not...

Comment: It is the multiBarChart, here string dates are accepted, do you think the multiChart is different? Why some charts would work and no others, after all parsing dates is independent of charts. I use lot of scripts for rendering the stuff, i am going to build a working multiBarChart with string dates, gonna take time.

Comment: I think the charts with a **scalar axis** have this issue. Charts with distinct axis values could be able to handle that. But this is lots of guessing, as I haven't worked with nvd3 for some months...

Comment: I give up, I will send dates in milliseconds for nv to interpret correctly. Still, there is no a satisfactory answer on why string dates doesn't work on this kind of chart.